# Reducing legend spacing only applies to one legend type in ggplt2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a figure with multiple legends and when I try to reduce the spacing between the key items, it only applies the change to my `geom_boxplot` `fill` legend and not my `geom_point` `shape` legend. I cannot fit my entire legend in my printed figure of 3x3 inches.

I have provided a couple of the rows of the data here to make the example reproducible

DATA:

```
> dput(Moment_UG.84[sample(nrow(Moment_UG.84), 20), ])
structure(list(UG = c(84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 
84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84), S = c(9, 12, 9, 12, 
12, 15, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12, 9, 12, 15, 12, 15, 15, 9, 12, 12), 
N_l = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
2, 2, 3), Sample = c(NA, "Sample", NA, NA, "Sample", "Sample", 
"Sample", "Sample", NA, NA, NA, "Sample", "Sample", "Sample", 
"Sample", NA, NA, "Sample", NA, NA), EQ = c("Puckett", "CSI", 
"AASHTO", "Shahawy", "CSI", "CSI", "CSI", "CSI", "Rigid", 
"Puckett_single.", "Phuvor", "CSI", "CSI", "CSI", "CSI", 
"Phuvor", "Henry", "CSI", "Rigid", "Phuvor"), DF = c(1.3294, 
0.56619579017746, 0.664107167708964, 0.918312684303714, 0.663377355412308, 
0.769602743779478, 0.992450316177789, 0.459974067878652, 
0.472, 1.276, 1.67608009117722, 0.45274352764964, 0.399417406036556, 
0.627034787482155, 0.584398599194936, 1.97077029619609, 1.07454545454545, 
0.544459041795895, 0.926666666666667, 1.67608009117722), 
Girder = c("Exterior", "Exterior", "Interior", "Exterior", 
"Interior", "Interior", "Exterior", "Interior", "Interior", 
"Interior", "Exterior", "Exterior", "Interior", "Exterior", 
"Exterior", "Exterior", "Interior", "Interior", "Exterior", 
"Interior"), Loading = c("Multi", "Single", "Multi", "Multi", 
"Multi", "Multi", "Multi", "Single", "Single", "Multi", "Multi", 
"Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Multi", 
"Multi", "Multi", "Multi"), X = c("Exterior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Exterior Girder\nSingle-lane", "Interior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Exterior Girder\nMulti-lane", "Interior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Interior Girder\nMulti-lane", "Exterior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Interior Girder\nSingle-lane", "Interior Girder\nSingle-lane", 
"Interior Girder\nMulti-lane", "Exterior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Exterior Girder\nSingle-lane", "Interior Girder\nSingle-lane", 
"Exterior Girder\nSingle-lane", "Exterior Girder\nSingle-lane", 
"Exterior Girder\nSingle-lane", "Interior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Interior Girder\nMulti-lane", "Exterior Girder\nMulti-lane", 
"Interior Girder\nMulti-lane")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Current code for creating the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "CSI"), 
   aes(x = X, y = DF, fill = factor(S,levels = c("9","12","15")))) +  theme_classic() +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
             fatten = 0.2, lwd = 0.2) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=0.5, stroke = 0.2,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5, lwd = 0.2, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "AASHTO"), 
           aes(shape = EQ), stroke = 0.2, size = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Henry"), 
           aes(shape = EQ), stroke = 0.2, size = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Suks"), 
           aes(shape = EQ), stroke = 0.2, size = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Shahawy"), 
           aes(shape = EQ), stroke = 0.2, size = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Rigid"), 
           aes(shape = EQ), stroke = 0.2, size = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
      labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank(), 
     title ="Ultra-Girder Section: UG-84",
     fill = "Girder Spacing (ft):", shape = element_blank()) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(0,0,6,0), 
                                 size = 7, face = "bold"), 
      legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=5, colour="black"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=5, colour="black"),
      axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 0.1), 
      axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.1),
      legend.text = element_text(size=5),
      legend.spacing.x = unit(0.01, 'cm'),
      legend.title = element_text(size=5))
```

Code to print my figure at the size needed:

```
png(filename="mypath\\fig1.png",
    type="cairo",
    units="in", 
    width=3, 
    height=3, 
    pointsize=12, 
    res=1200)
print(a)
dev.off()
```

Finally, the figure I get:

[image]

Comment: The shape legend keys are probably spaced the same as the boxplot keys, however, the shape legend keys are mostly empty space, which gives the appearance of the spacing not being the same. You can try and set `+ guides(shape = guide_legend(keywidth = unit(3, "mm")))` or whatever unit suits you best.

Comment: @teunbrand You solved it! haha thanks! This reduced the spacing between each legend item and its label, as well as the different legend items. Is there a way to only reduce the spacing between each legend item and its corresponding label? the actual figure I am trying to produce has a lot more going on with facets and looks a little confusing now.

Comment: @teunbrand Unless you have a more direct solution, just posting if anyone else is interested, the spacing between the different legend items could be possibly adjusted by changing the `legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(0,5,0,0))`. The only issue is that this is applied to both labels for `fill` and `shape` I couldn't find a `guide` option for the margins to overwrite it for just the `shape` legend labels